# Ignoring a certain column in MS Access SELECT DISTINCTROW

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Title, Author, Genre, ISBN, UID, YearPurchased, Condition
from " + table + "
WHERE " + condition + " " + defOrder + ";
```

which is called through UCanAccess in Java.

Is there any way, using the SQL, to have the query output to a ResultSet (I have this already coded and working) where subsequent records with duplicate Titles and ISBNs (when a boolean is true) are removed (other column names can have duplicates).

Example
Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Title, Author, Genre, ISBN, UID, YearPurchased, Condition 
from tblBooks 
WHERE (Title LIKE 'spit*' OR Author LIKE 'spit*' OR Genre LIKE 'spit*') AND Loaned = No 
ORDER BY Title;
```

Desired output is without the 2nd record:

https://prnt.sc/s67k2q

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added Example query and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  I'm not sure what you are exactly defining a single row, but this works for the data you provided:

```
SELECT Title, Author, Genre, ISBN, MIN(UID) as UID, YearPurchased, Condition
from " + table + "
WHERE " + condition + " " + defOrder + "
GROUP BY Title, Author, Genre, ISBN, YearPurchased, Condition
```

Comment: Works fantastic! Thanks for the fast reply and apologies for the badly worded question.